# Does the Android SDK Emulator mount the filesystems on the host or emulate the mounting?

Tags: file-system, google, android-emulator, android-sdk, android-studio

Does the Android Studio Emulator mount filesystems (like `system.img` and `userdata-qemu.img`) or emulate the mounting by making an illusion because I can't find them (the mounted filesystems) on the host at all.

Comment: Those images are part of the Android SDK packages. Check the android SDK directory `android-sdk/system-images/android-<Android-API-level>` and below.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I know that but this doesn't answer the question. Where are they mounted on the host if they are should be mounted on running the emulator? or are they used by the emulator without mounting?

Comment: You wrote that you can't find them (the files) on the host, therefore I wrote that comment. May be your question was not well formulated?

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. Never mind. plz, if the question should be more clear, feel free to edit it.

Comment: The `*.img`s of the AVD are located in the directory `~/.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>` on the host system. In the configuration file `~/.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>/hardware-qemu.ini`  you can find which images are mounted. May be this link can help: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: @St0rm I want to know where is it mounted on the host not which image is mounted.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the emulator uses virtual disk image files as storage. I'd assume it mounts that file instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, the emulator does not mount the filesystems of the emulated device on the host.

If it did that, it would be impractical to emulate more than one device at a time.

The emulator is intended for application development and testing. If the filesystems of an emulated device were easy to modify, that would make it hard to be sure applications that worked on the emulator would work on a normal device.